# Why does LSTM Aggregation in PyG need to sort edge_index?

Tags: python, pytorch, neural-network, lstm, pytorch-geometric

*Hello, I have used [GraphSAGE](https://pytorch-geometric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/torch_geometric.nn.conv.SAGEConv.html) to do Node embedding. The function I chose to use for aggregate is [LSTM](https://pytorch-geometric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/torch_geometric.nn.aggr.LSTMAggregation.html#torch_geometric.nn.aggr.LSTMAggregation) with the library of [PyG](https://pytorch-geometric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/nn.html) for Graph Neural Network, the arguments it needs are follow:*

**Input 1: Node features (|V|, F_in)** - Here I use Node coordinates x-y in 2D plane (V x 2) and already normalized into the range of [0, 1] e.g.

```
          x         y
0  0.374540  0.598658
1  0.950714  0.156019
2  0.731994  0.155995
```

**Input 2: Edge indices (2, |E|)** - Adjacency matrix (V x V) but retrieves only the edge into (2, |E|)  from the original adjacency matrix I have e.g.

```
idx   0  1  2
0   [[0, 1, 1], 
1    [1, 0, 1], 
2    [1, 1, 0]]
```

Above we have a shape (V x V) with 6 edges in the graph. We had to transform it a bit to accommodate PyG's use of shape (2, |E|) and I'd like to call it `edge_index` where edges is (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1).

```
idx   0  1  2  3  4  5
0   [[0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2],
1    [1, 2, 0, 2, 0, 1]]
```

**Output: Node features (|V|, F_out)** - Similar to Node coordinates, but they are not in 2D anymore, they are in a new embedding dimension with F_out dimensions.

My problem is that when using the LSTM aggregator it is forced to sort `edge_index` (Edge indices in input2) otherwise it will show an error saying `ValueError: Can not perform aggregation since the 'index' tensor. is not sorted.`

So I have to do [sorting](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.sort.html) gives it with the following command:

```py
# inside def __init__()
self.graph_sage=SAGEConv(in_channels=2, out_channels=hidden_dim, aggr='lstm')

# inside def forward()
sorted_edge_index, _ = torch.sort(edge_index, dim=1)  # for LSTM
x = self.graph_sage(coord.view(-1, 2), sorted_edge_index)  # using GraphSAGE
```

The `sorted_edge_index` tensor will look like this after sorting.

```
idx   0  1  2  3  4  5
0   [[0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2],
1    [0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2]]
```

I noticed that in my full-mesh graph of 3 nodes connected, when I sorted it, the edges could be reinterpreted as (0, 0), (0, 0), (1, 1), (1, 1), (2, 2), (2, 2) which made me curious. And my questions are the following 2 things.

1. Why does LSTM need to sort the `edge_index`?
2. After I sort `edge_index` like this, how will my model know which nodes are connected? Because all the original edge relationship pairs are gone. It's like sending edge pairs that don't exist in the graph as input. Will this be a disadvantage?

I have tried doing the above and it ran fine. But I have some doubts and hope someone knowledgeable will help clarify things for a beginner like me. And I sincerely hope this question can be useful to other students studying GNN as well.

Comment: Please remember that Stack Overflow is not your favourite Python forum, but rather a question and answer site for all programming related questions. Thus, always include the tag of the language you are programming in, that way other users familiar with that language can more easily find your question. Take the [tour] and read up on [ask] to get more information on how this site works, then [edit] the question with the relevant tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sort by row = False

```py
from torch_geometric.utils import sort_edge_index

sorted_edge_index = sort_edge_index(edge_index, num_nodes=self.num_nodes, sort_by_row=False)
x = self.graph_sage(coord.view(-1, 2), sorted_edge_index)
```

https://github.com/pyg-team/pytorch_geometric/discussions/8908